# Ambiguous Column Name query

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying to do inner join into the salesfacts table, i always get the ambiguous error like:

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Ambiguous column name 'officeCode'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Ambiguous column name 'officeCode'.
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

**Code to insert into SalesFacts Table**

```
truncate table SalesFacts

INSERT INTO Assignment1SS..SalesFacts
(ProductCode, CustomerNumber, EmployeeNumber, officeCode, buyPrice, MSRP, quantityOrdered)

SELECT 
p.ProductCode, 
c.CustomerNumber, 
e.EmployeeNumber, 
y.officeCode, 
p.buyPrice, 
p.MSRP, 
od.quantityOrdered

FROM
Assignemnt1..[OrderDetails] od INNER JOIN Assignemnt1..[Orders] o
ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[ProductSS] p 
ON od.productCode = p.productCode

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[CustomersSS] c
ON od.OrderNumber = c.CustomerNumber

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[EmployeeSS] e
ON c.SalesRepEmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber

INNER JOIN

(select [EmployeeNumber], [officeCode]
from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e
inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y
on e.officeCode = y.officeCode
group by [EmployeeNumber],[officeCode]) y

on e.EmployeeNumber = c.salesRepEmployeeNumber
```

**Offices Table**

```
Create Table Offices(
officeCode varchar (10) NOT NULL,
City varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Phone varchar (50) NOT NULL,
AddressLine1 varchar (50) NOT NULL,
AddressLine2 varchar (50) NULL,
State varchar (50) NULL,
Country varchar (50) NOT NULL,
PostalCode varchar (15) NOT NULL,
Territory varchar (10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (OfficeCode));
```

**Employees Table**

```
Create Table Employees (
EmployeeNumber int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Extension varchar (10) NOT NULL,
Email varchar (100) NOT NULL,
officeCode varchar (10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Offices(officeCode) NOT NULL,
ReportsTo int NULL,
JobTitle varchar (50),
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeNumber));
```

**Update**:
This works for me (select e.[EmployeeNumber], y.[officeCode] from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y on e.officeCode = y.officeCode group by e.[EmployeeNumber],y.[officeCode])

Comment: Add table aliases here `(select e.[EmployeeNumber], y.[officeCode]
from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e
inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y
on e.officeCode = y.officeCode
group by e.[EmployeeNumber],y.[officeCode]) y`

Comment: i used your method, but now it works but it says that 0 rows affected, why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    SELECT 

    p.ProductCode, 
    c.CustomerNumber, 
    e.EmployeeNumber, 
    y.officeCode, 
    p.buyPrice, 
    p.MSRP, 
    od.quantityOrdered

    FROM
    Assignemnt1..[OrderDetails] od INNER JOIN Assignemnt1..[Orders] o
    ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber

    INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[ProductSS] p 
    ON od.productCode = p.productCode

    INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[CustomersSS] c
    ON od.OrderNumber = c.CustomerNumber

    INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[EmployeeSS] e
    ON c.SalesRepEmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber

    INNER JOIN

    (select [EmployeeNumber], y.[officeCode]
    from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e
    inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y
    on e.officeCode = y.officeCode
    group by [EmployeeNumber],y.officeCode) y
on e.EmployeeNumber = c.salesRepEmployeeNumber
```

Comment: it shows me this error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near 'y'.

Comment: @kkbqsz5f you query is not complete so now you can specify inner join to last on...

Comment: i added the last inner join line (on e.EmployeeNumber = c.salesRepEmployeeNumber)

Comment: now it shows me this error : Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
Ambiguous column name 'officeCode'.

Comment: @kkbqsz5f now check you

Comment: i tried everything i could, and now it shows 0 rows affected even though all my tables have the necessary data

Comment: @kkbqsz5f i resolve stuff of Ambiguous Column not logic